# Photo gallery to embed on my own homepage?

Tags: embed, photo-gallery

Is it possible to embed flickr or picasa (or similar) web-album on my own homepage.

I don't want just a link to flickr's gallery, I want to embed the gallery like vimeo and youtube-clips.

I have looked around on flickr and picasa but did't find a solution... hope you can help me :)

Comment: This is not related to embedded software.

Comment: Not a programming question either.

Comment: I know, sorry, do you know a better forum to post this question? Anyway, I do get good answers...

Comment: My first ever Perl project was a CGI script to automatically generate photo album pages for my web site (see http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.misc/browse_thread/thread/7116804b2635b478/62c8fa5315a4645e ) Maybe you can use this as a motivation for your programming project.

Answer (score 1):

For Flickr:
Add your pics to a set(maybe its working with galleries too but not tested by my own).
Open the set and click on the slideshow button on the right.
Then click on the share button on the top-right corner, copy the "embed HTML" and paste it in you html page and you are ready )